# Mocking two different implementation of an Interface in Controller Mockito Junit test case

Tags: spring-boot, controller, mockito, junit4, junit5

I have an interface(Client) with two implementation classes PClient and SClient respectively.

```
Interface  - Client
Impl class - PCleint, SClient
```

I have a controller in which both the impl classes are autowired using qualifier spring boot annotation. Now i need to write JUNIT mockito test case for the controller.

I am not sure how to mock the different Impl classes which has the same interface. I tried mocking in the following way but it throws null pointer exception in the stub method of the respective mocks.

```
@Mock
private Client pclient

@Mock 
private Client sclient
```

How do i differentiate mocking different impl classes such that the methods of the impl classes are called. Should i do like the below.

```
@Mock
private PClient pclient

@Mock 
private SClient sclient
```

It did not work for me . Either one throws null pointer exception . Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the tricks are you need to use `Before` to stub the return value and use `@InjectMocks` for the controller. 
Since `@Mock` won't return a "real" object, it just return a "mock"(or fake:P ) one. So when you call a method of this "mock" object, it won't return the actual output from your method, instead it gives back `null`. That's why you need to stub the return with `@Before`.

See my example code below:

**Client Interface**

```
public interface Client {
    String someMethod();
}
```

**Class implemented**

```
public class PClient implements Client {
    private static final String name = "PClient";
    @Override
    public String someMethod() {
        return name;
    }
}


public class SClient implements Client{
    private static final String name = "SClient";
    @Override
    public String someMethod() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**The Client Controller**

@Controller
public class ClientController {

```
@Autowired
private PClient pClient;
@Autowired
private SClient sClient;

public ClientController(){
}
public String executePClient(){
    return this.pClient.someMethod();
}

public String executeSClient(){
    return this.sClient.someMethod();
}

public String execute(Client client){
    return client.someMethod();
}
```

}

**The test case** You need to add a `@Before` to stub the method return.

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ClientControllerTest {
    @Mock
    private PClient pclient;
    @Mock
    private SClient sclient;
    @InjectMocks
    private ClientController clientController;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        when(pclient.someMethod()).thenReturn(new PClient().someMethod());
        when(sclient.someMethod()).thenReturn(new SClient().someMethod());
    }

    @Test
    public void testPClient(){
        String result = clientController.executePClient();
        assertEquals("PClient",result);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSClient(){
        String result = clientController.executeSClient();
        assertEquals("SClient",result);
    }

    @Test
    public void testExecuteWithPClient(){
        String result = clientController.execute(pclient);
        assertEquals("PClient",result);
    }

    @Test
    public void testExecuteWithSClient(){
        String result = clientController.execute(sclient);
        assertEquals("SClient",result);
    }
}
```

Result: Tests passed: 4 of 4 tests - 31ms

Comment: I have a question here. I am using init method can i stub it inside it instead of setup

Comment: Do you mean pass in the "Client" into the constructor then test it?